# Macro to compute number of bits needed to store a number n

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, bit

Let's say I need to write **C** macro that returns number of bits(1..32) needed to store unsigned 32-bit integer. (Result equals ceiling(log2(n)).

I need it as compile-time computed macro, not a function.

I could do

```
 #define NBITS(n) ((n)&(1<<31)?32:(n)&(1<<30)?31:...
```

it works, but is rather long. (Speed does not matter here, computation is at compile time).

Is there shorter way to write this macro ? Shortest ?

Comment: Does it have to be in C? In C++0x I could offer a variadic template to do this... The C preprocessor doesn't appear to allow recursive macros, alas.

Comment: simple C++ will do with a recursive template

Comment: Why the hell would you use a macro for this instead of an inline function? Besides that you should use every macro argument exactly once (and certainly not more than once) - otherwise bad things happen if you call the macro e.g. on a function with side-effects or an expensive function.

Comment: Do you need the exact number of bits? A more practical solution would be to know how many bytes you would need for storage, so you could AND with 0xFF000000, 0xFF0000, 0xFF00 and 0xFF.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: This is C question.

Comment: @hexa: Need exact number of bits.

Comment: have a look at [bithacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogObvious) super link for bit-manipulations

Comment: @ThiefMaster: For compile-time constants it would be useful to evaluate this at compile time. Perhaps a macro'ed runtime expression would be optimized away, though. yi_H: Yes, ordinary template, not variadic. Sorry.

Comment: It is probably prudent to check that `n` is a constant.  For example, gcc supplies `__builtin_constant_p`.  If the macro is used with a non-constant, then the computation is a run-time calculation.  This is a great question to reset a pointer within an [aligned buffer](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/kfifo.h). Also useful for normalization. See: [Linux log2.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/log2.h#n85)

Answer (score 10):

```
#define NBITS2(n) ((n&2)?1:0)
#define NBITS4(n) ((n&(0xC))?(2+NBITS2(n>>2)):(NBITS2(n)))
#define NBITS8(n) ((n&0xF0)?(4+NBITS4(n>>4)):(NBITS4(n)))
#define NBITS16(n) ((n&0xFF00)?(8+NBITS8(n>>8)):(NBITS8(n)))
#define NBITS32(n) ((n&0xFFFF0000)?(16+NBITS16(n>>16)):(NBITS16(n)))
#define NBITS(n) (n==0?0:NBITS32(n)+1)
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << NBITS(0) << endl;
    cout << NBITS(1) << endl;
    cout << NBITS(2) << endl;
    cout << NBITS(3) << endl;
    cout << NBITS(4) << endl;
    cout << NBITS(1023) << endl;
    cout << NBITS(1024) << endl;
}
```

it is good?

Comment: I would argue you still need 1 bit to **store** the value 0.

Comment: I think this is supposed to be C, not C++.

Comment: For anyone curious, I wrote up an explanation of how this works for a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29283276/calling-a-function-from-a-macro/29291166

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind additional statements (while loop) the following will work in c99

```
#define NBITS_32(n,out_len) 0; while (n && !(0x80000000 >> out_len & n)) out_len++; out_len = n ? abs(out_len - 32) : n


uint8_t len1 = NBITS_32(0x0F000000, len1);
uint8_t len2 = NBITS_32(0x00008000, len2);
uint8_t len3 = NBITS_32(0xFFFFFFFF, len3);
uint8_t len4 = NBITS_32(0x00000001, len4);

printf("%u\n%u\n%u\n%u\n", len1, len2, len3, len4);
```

Output:

> **28
>  16
>  32
>  1**

Comment: -1: The macro does not expand to a compile-time constant as demanded by the question.

Comment: It will, but the macro expands to two statements. Hence, you cannot do something like 'int arr[NBITS_32(...)]' which you *can* do if the macro expands to a compile-time constant (as is the case with Adi's solution)

Comment: I realized that after thinking about it for more than 2 seconds :). Thanks I will leave as a reference unless it gets a bunch of down votes. Adi's answer seems good

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a macro that does a bit less test than what you propose in your question, by using a more clever bit testing for several bits at a time. The macro `P99_HIGH2` from [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/) implements such a trick as was already mentioned in one of the comments. If this is used for compile time expressions, there is no danger in evaluating the argument several times, since this must be an integer constant expression, anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution for C, but for C++ (c++11 or higher), constexpr instead of MACRO is a way to go.

```
constexpr int log2(unsigned int word) {     
    return word ? (1 + log2(word>>1)) : 0; 
};
```

The compiler will do evaluation at compile time and replace the call (e.g. log2(16)) with a literal value (e.g. 5), provided -O2 or -O3 optimization is used (because of the recursive call).

Answer (score -3):

I don't think the C preprocessor is able to do this. If I'm not mistaking, you can't place preprocessor if statements in a macro. All you can do is a piece of code with holes, with the parameters of the macro filling the holes.

Comment: I gave working example. It works and is staticlly compiled but it is long. How can you think it is not possible when I gave working example ? Or you want me to give the full rhs ?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you where talking about C++, I assumed you wanted to get the macro output directly giving you you number of bits, for this purpose I would have expected a function. Also, depending on your compiler optimisations, you might try to put it in a for loop.

Comment: his macro does give you the number of bits. btw you can put `if` statements in a macro, but the place where you use it has to be a statement, won't work inside an expression.

Comment: You can put if statement, but not #if. I was thinking about optimising storage types, where you would need the information before the optimisation process.